# Question about homomorphism of algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, algebras

> Let $f: \Bbb{Q}[[x]]\rightarrow\Bbb{Q}[[x]]$ be a $\Bbb{Q}$ homomorphism of algebras and $f$ sends every inverse element in inverse elements.

> a)Show that $f(\langle x \rangle)\subset \langle x \rangle $

> b) Is that true also for powers $\langle x \rangle^k$

> Proof: a) If we take an element $h$ in $\langle x \rangle$ and say that $g=f(h)$ is not in $\langle x \rangle$, then $g(0)=c \in \Bbb{Q}^*$ and $h-c\in \Bbb{Q}[[x]]^*$. But then $f(h-c)=g-g(0)\in\langle x \rangle$ would be not invertible.
> Proof: b)Yes, since $\langle x \rangle^k=\langle x^k \rangle$ and $f(\langle x \rangle^k)=\langle f(x^k) \rangle=\langle f(x)^k \rangle \in \langle x \rangle^k$.

Why from $g=f(h)$ is not in $\langle x \rangle$, follows $g(0)=c \in \Bbb{Q}^*$ and $h-c\in \Bbb{Q}[[x]]^*$ and $f(h-c)$ would not be invertible in a)
And in b: could somebody please explain me the equalities, does it follow from properties of functions or polynomials?

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Question about (a): The invertible elements in $\mathbb{C}[[x]]$ are those in which the "constant term" is non-zero. If you subtract $h-c$, now the "constant term" of $h-c$ is $-c\neq0$. So, $h-c$ is invertible. On the other hand $f(h-c)=f(h)-f(c)=g-c$ is in $\langle x\rangle$. So, it is not invertible.

Comment: About (b): Well, these are power series. The elements of $\langle x\rangle$ are those power series that are multiples of $x$. In $\langle x\rangle^k$ you have products of series that each is a multiple of $x$. Therefore the product is a multiple of $x^k$. Conversely, in $\langle x^k\rangle$ you have series that are multiple of $x^k$ i.e. of the form $x^kg(x)$ for some $g\in\mathbb{C}[[x]]$. You can think that this is equal to the product of the $k$ factors $x,x,x,...,xg(x)$. So, $\langle x\rangle^k=\langle x^k\rangle$.

Comment: The last few equalities are again using the definition of each of the ideals involved. besides that, that main other feature being used is that $f$ distributes with respect to sum and products of series.

Comment: @plop Why don't you convert your three comments into an answer?